# Создание одного массива из нескольких

Tags: массивы, php

Всем привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите, пожалуйста, с решением проблемы.

Есть к примеру три массива след. вида:

```
Array (
            [0] => ID
            [1] => ID
            [3] => ID
    )
Array (
            [0] => DATE
            [1] => DATE
            [3] => DATE
    )
Array (
            [0] => TEXT
            [1] => TEXT
            [3] => TEXT
    )
```

Нужно сделать из этих трех один массив след. вида:

```
Array (
    Array (
            [0] => ID
            [1] => DATE
            [3] => TEXT
    )
    Array (
            [0] => ID
            [1] => DATE
            [3] => TEXT
    )
    Array (
            [0] => ID
            [1] => DATE
            [3] => TEXT
    )
)
```

Вот таким образом формирую массивы:

```
// Ищем названия новостей
$array_nameNews = array();
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div h2 a') as $element) {    
    $nameNews = $element->innertext;
    $array_nameNews[] = $nameNews;
}

// Ищем дату публикации
$array_dateNews = array();
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate') as $element) {
    $dateNews = $element->innertext;
    $array_dateNews[] = $dateNews;
}
```

*Результат работы первого цикла `foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div h2 a') as $element)`*

```
Array ( 
    [0] => some text...
    [1] => some text...
    [2] => some text...
    [3] => some text... 
    [n] => и т.д.
)
```

*Результат работы второго цикла `foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate') as $element) as $element)`*

```
Array ( 
    [0] => some date...
    [1] => some date...
    [2] => some date...
    [3] => some date... 
    [n] => и т.д.
)
```

**НЕОБХОДИМО ТАК:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => some text...
    [1] => some date...
)
Array ( 
    [0] => some text...
    [1] => some date...
)
Array ( 
    [0] => some text...
    [1] => some date...
)
Array ( 
    и т.д.
)
```

Comment: @archi_sova, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$param_array = array();
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
  $arrname = 'arr'.$i;
  $param_array[] = count($$arrname);// бегаем по массивам по циклу. arr_name может доставать имена из массива имен. Никто не мешает.
}

$min_size = call_user_func_array('min');

$container = array();
for($i=0;$i<$min_size;$i++){
  $container[$i] = array();
  for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
    $arrname = 'arr'.$i;
    $container[$i][] = array_shift($$arrname);// бегаем по массивам по циклу. Можно использовать pop, можно shift. Что больше соответствует заданию.
  }
}
```

min_size нужна для того чтобы у нас результирующий массив получился гарантированно заполненным.

P.S. загрузку файлов делаете, ага? =)

Comment: спасибо! вкусняшка :) начинаю пробовать...

Comment: *загрузку файлов делаете, ага?
>ага! это как раз в продолжение [этой темы][1], вы мне там уже помогали, спасибо большое, 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/165639/php-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: @knes а объясните, пожалуйста, чего куда подставить, сориентироваться никак не могу, я в вопросе дополнил описание.

Comment: В Вашем случае надо немного изменить принцип именования.

    $data_names_array = array(1=>'name',2=>'date');
    //.....
    $arrname = 'array_'.$data_names_array[$i].'News; //сформируется array_dateNews или array_nameNews в зависимости от $i

Comment: @knes Куда, чего поставить... ?